# Image of a weak convergent sequence

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, continuity, weak-convergence

Let $u_n$ be weakly convergent to $u$ in $H^1(\Omega)$

where $H^1(\Omega)=\{u\in L^2(\Omega), \frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}\in L^2(\Omega), i=1,\ldots,N\}$, $\Omega$ is a bounded from $\mathbb{R}^N.$

and $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a $C^1$ function with $f(0)=0$

Do we have that $f\circ u_n$ converges weakly in $H^1(\Omega)$?

Comment: No, $f \circ u_n$ may not belong to $H^1(\Omega)$. Take some $u_n$ with a singularity and $f(x) = x^\alpha$ for some $\alpha > 1$.

Comment: @gerw i don't find an example, if you have one please give it to me

Comment: For $N > 2$ you can take $u_n(x) = \|x\|^\beta$ for suitable chosen $\beta < 0$.